Who are Hexaly's competitors?
Quoting from Hexaly's website here and here:

Hexaly Optimizer is a new kind of mathematical optimization solver


It is important to understand that Hexaly Optimizer is not a MIP solver. More precisely Hexaly Optimizer is more than a MIP solver.

Or:

Hexaly Optimizer does not rely on tree-based search

It looks like the alternatives or competitors of Hexaly are not the traditional Optimization solvers (HiGHS, Gurobi, etc.), which I believe, and correct me if I am mistaken, all rely on tree-based search for combinatorial optimization problems.
Then, a question that comes to my mind is: are there alternatives to Hexaly? Is there an Operations Research community that develops an open source software that also aims to be "more" than a MIP solver and belongs to this category of "new kind of mathematical optimization solver"? Or do they rule a monopoly, at least for the moment?

No one ever has a monopoly on hype or hyperbole.

@MarkL.Stone, I would select your comment as my question's answer ;)

Hexaly competes with Mixed-Integer Linear Programming (MILP) solvers and all the other solvers available for combinatorial optimization, like Constraint Programming (CP) solvers.
Hexaly is unique in the sense that its modeling APIs, available through Python, Java, C#, or C++, are unique in the actual market. They are nonlinear and set-oriented. The introduction of "set" and "list" variables, as well as all related set and list arithmetic operators, is new. This makes the modeling of combinatorial problems much easier while enabling the exploitation of state-of-the-art algorithmic techniques not exploited inside MILP solvers, like Branch-Cut-Price and Local Search methods, among others.
Hexaly is not specific to certain types of problems. You can use Hexaly to tackle any problem, even black-box optimization problems, since Hexaly admits you define/plug external functions in your optimization model. Now, we don't claim Hexaly is the best for everything. We claim Hexaly makes a huge difference in speed, scalability, and robustness against MILP solvers and any other solver to solve combinatorial problems like Routing, Scheduling, Packing, Clustering, Assignment, and Location problems, among others. Note that it works on mixed-variable (discrete + continuous) extensions of these problems, like Inventory Routing problems. Check the benchmarks here; anyone can reproduce the results using the templates given in Hexaly's example tour.
Hexaly is a commercial software product. It is free for academics. Register here to get a free trial or free academic license.

Could you elaborate more on the "set" and "list" variables?

@MatheusDiógenesAndrade You can check the Hexaly website for details. First, the modeling concepts: https://www.hexaly.com/docs/last/modelingfeatures/index.html. Second, some modeling examples: https://www.hexaly.com/docs/last/exampletour/index.html

The competitor keywords that Hexaly actively targets with Google Search advertisements are:

Timefold
Gurobi
OR-Tools
OptaPlanner
Cplex


As I understand it, Hexaly asks you to write your model in a somewhat different form from other solvers (using sets and lists, the latter being an ordered set) rather than numeric variables (your typical $x_{i,j}\in S$). Under the hood, it has a collection of solvers for a variety of problem types, plus plumbing to let you hook in your own solver. My impression is that most (all?) of the solvers are heuristics, not guaranteed to produce provably optimal solutions even given adequate time and memory.
So the closest you are likely to come to a competitor is something with solvers for multiple problem types. OR-Tools certainly comes to mind. CPLEX Studio comes with two types of solver, CPLEX (LP/IP/QP) and CP Optimizer (CP). SAS has an optimization suite with a very large number of solvers (something like 15 network solvers alone, plus other problem types), but I'm pretty sure they are all math programming solvers of some kind.

Hexaly is not a portfolio of solvers. Specifically, it doesn't select a solver for a problem type. Hexaly combines primal and dual methods into a global optimization solver. Its modeling API is nonlinear and set-oriented. It also supports black-box optimization. It can be viewed as an extension of both MINLP and CP solvers. No other solver supports such a modeling API. Check examples here: https://www.hexaly.com/docs/last/exampletour/index.html

Apparently, Hexaly's proposal is a solver designed for specific types of problems: "Routing, Scheduling, Packing, and more". Since I haven't tested yet, we would need to do a comparison (Commercial solvers: CPLEX, Gurobi; Non-commercial: COIN-or) in more generic problems. Hexaly is the former Local Solver.

I saw a talk at ISMP where one of the founders presented results that showed it was compatible, or even surpassing, Gurobi on some TSPs. The instances were undisclosed, however, or I didn't catch them, at least. What I got from the presentation was that they put a special emphasis on logical constraints and data structures.

@J.Dionisio The instances are disclosed: the TSPLIB. The benchmark is given here: https://www.hexaly.com/benchmark/hexaly-vs-gurobi-traveling-salesman-problem-tsp. Ask for free Gurobi and Hexaly licenses; you can easily reproduce the results. You can check all our benchmarks here: https://www.hexaly.com/benchmarks

Appreciate the comment, @Hexaly, I didn't mean to doubt your claims. All the best.
